# Python SOAP Client Nested Request

Tags: python, soap, request

I got a problem with a Python SOAP request.
I tested two python SOAP client libraries so far: SUDS and pysimplesoap.
Both work well for the following example:

```
from suds.client import Client
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient, SoapFault

# suds example
url = "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL"
client = Client(url, cache=None)

print client.service.GetGeoIP((ip))


# pysimplesoap example
client = SoapClient(wsdl="http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL")

# call the remote method
response = client.GetGeoIP(("10.0.1.152"))

print response
```

Both work fine and give me the expected response:

```
{'GetGeoIPResult': {'ReturnCodeDetails': 'Success', 'IP': '10.0.1.152', 'ReturnCode': 1, 'CountryName': 'Reserved', 'CountryCode': 'ZZZ'}}
```

With a UI SOAP testing programm the request looks like this:

```
-<soap:Envelope>
    -<soap:Body>
        -<GetGeoIP>
            <IPAddress>("10.0.1.152")</IPAddress>
        </GetGeoIP>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now the problem is, I need to contact another WS via SOAP, but that doesn't work. With the UI SOAP program it works (keys and token can be empty) and looks like:

```
-<soap:Envelope>
    -<soap:Body>
        -<getNews>
            -<shrequest>
                <data>{'account_number':202VA7, 'track_nr':1757345939}</data>
                <function>getnewsdata</function>
                <keys/>
                <token/>
            </shrequest>
        </getNews>
     </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

But my code doesn't work:

```
url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = Client(url, cache=None)

data = "{'account_number':202VA7, 'track_nr':1757345939}"
function = "getnewsdata"
keys = ""
token = ""
shrequest = [data,function,keys,token]

response = client.service.getNews(shrequest)

print response
```

I get:

```
ValueError('Invalid Args Structure. Errors: %s' % errors)
ValueError: Invalid Args Structure. Errors:
```

How do I have to nest my request right?

Comment: You might want to change `{'account_number':202VA7` to `{'account_number':'202VA7'`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but since data is a whole string, that doesn't matter. It's the same parameter I use with the UI program and works fine there, too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. The SUDS library offers sth. nice:

```
url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl"
client = Client(url, cache=None)

# Creating 'shrequest' obj. before the request
shrequest = client.factory.create('shrequest')
shrequest.data = "{'account_number':202VA7, 'track_nr':1757345939}"
shrequest.function = "getnewsdata"

response = client.service.getShipment(shrequest)

print response
```